# MySQL Query to Pull Distinct Id with Multiple WHEREs

Tags: sql, mysql, correlation

I am having a brain freeze with what originally I thought would be a simple query.

I have a table like the following:

```
ID   DETAILID    NAME    
-------------------------------------------------
1    1           Sed ut perspiciatis unde
2    1           omnis iste natus error
3    1           sit voluptatem accusantium
4    1           doloremque laudantium
5    2           totam rem aperiam
6    2           labore et dolore
7    3           voluptate velit esse
8    3           occaecati cupiditate non
9    3           culpa qui officia
10   3           placeat facere possimus
11   3           Nam libero tempore
```

I want to search the NAME field multiple times with LIKE '%%' (number of LIKE's will be random) but I only want to return a distinct DETAILID where the LIKE's are all found in records where the DETAILID is the same.

I am going round in circles and getting nowhere fast. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gives you the DETAILIDs that match all the LIKE conditions

```
SELECT DETAILID
FROM
(
    select DETAILID, 1 as WhichMatch
    from tbl
    where NAME LIKE '%a%'
    UNION ALL
    select DETAILID, 2 as WhichMatch
    from tbl
    where NAME LIKE '%b%'
    UNION ALL
    select DETAILID, 3 as WhichMatch
    from tbl
    where NAME LIKE '%c%'
) SQ
GROUP BY DETAILID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT WhichMatch) = 3
```

Comment: That gives the distinct detailid but the detailid is returned even if all the LIKE's are not true for the particular detailid. I need the detailid returned only if all the LIKE's are true for all the names that have the particular detailid. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @scampbell - Answer edited after reinterpreting your question

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick! Thanks very much. Any chance of an explanation of the query? I realise a temporary table is created but Im not sure how all the WhichMatch values are being calculated. Thanks again. Id vote your answer up but dont have enough rep as yet.

Comment: Once my rep hits 15 I most definetely will :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looking for ALL "LIKE" values to be found, you'll need an OR between them, a COUNT(*) to see how many match, and a GROUP BY per ID, and a HAVING to match the count you expect...

```
select 
      DETAILID,
      count(*) RecsFound
   from 
      YourTable
   where 
          NAME LIKE '%a%'
       or NAME LIKE '%b%'
       or NAME LIKE '%c%'
       or NAME LIKE '%d%'
   group by
      DetailID
   having
      RecsFound = 4
```

As you mentioned, it could be a random number of "like" qualifiers and sounds like it will be a dynamically constructed SQL Query.  As such, make sure your HAVING clause count matches those entries you are testing against.

EDIT - revised answer move IF() to where section

```
select 
      DETAILID
   from 
      YourTable
   where 
          if( NAME LIKE '%a%', 1, 0 ) 
        + if( NAME LIKE '%b%', 1, 0 ) 
        + if( NAME LIKE '%c%', 1, 0 ) 
        + if( NAME LIKE '%d%', 1, 0 ) = 4
```

I guess I was looking at it from a multi-rowed table where each entry was its own element you were testing for.  You are looking to have all values in the same ROW matching ALL the LIKEs...  Although you have accepted another answer, here's another alternative WITHOUT using all the distinct unions...

Additionally, goes through the table ONCE instead of 2, 3, 4 or more via all the unions, then having a group by...  It hits the record ONCE, qualifies all 4 conditions and is DONE.

Comment: Thanks very much. It is a dynamically constructed SQL query yes. Your example is great and would have worked apart from the fact that some of my names are very similar, so a like can find more than one record thereby increasing the count but still not all of the likes would have been found. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @scampbell, per your comment, here's a revised query that doesn't need complex unions and should STILL get the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I cant get this to work. I get the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'LikeMatches' in 'where clause'. If I take the where out and just run the query I can order by LikeMatches which seems very strange. But even when I do that order by on 3 matches (which the accepted code finds 4 matches of) LikeMatches only equals 2 for 2 identical detailid's. I know I could use a distinct but even then only 1 result would have 2 LikeMatches and none would have the 3 that is required.

Comment: @scampbell, I moved the IF() qualifiers to the WHERE... try that.

Comment: Thanks again. No errors this time but no results either with the same variables that return 4 hits on the working query. This seems to just check the 1 field, rather than all fields with the same detailid again though?

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT DETAILID 
FROM MyTable
WHERE NAME LIKE '%something%'
   or NAME LIKE '%sometingelse%
```

Comment: That gives the distinct DETAILID but the DETAILID is returned even if all the LIKE's are not true for the particular DETAILID. I need the DETAILID returned only if all the LIKE's are true for all the NAMEs that have the particular DETAILID. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well, after reading your comments on other two answers, I believe you need this -

Use **AND** instead of **OR** in the query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT DETAILID 
FROM MyTable
WHERE NAME LIKE '%something%'
   AND NAME LIKE '%someting1%'
   AND NAME LIKE '%someting2%'
```

Comment: In this case it will only return the DETAILID when the NAME for a single record contains all the LIKEs. I want it to return the DETAILID when all records with the same DETAILID contain all the LIKEs somewhere in that set of records. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest solution is to do it in multiple queries. 
Selecting the count() of the distinct id with a WHERE and selecting the count() of the distinct id without where condition.
Comparing those 2 would be a perfect way of determining wether all 'names' of 'detialids' match your LIKE's